# Segmentation fault using dlmalloc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am using [Doug Lea's dlmalloc memory allocator](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html). However I get segmentation when I use that. If I use the normal malloc my program runs fine. I remember I once read that you need to first call some initialization function for dlmalloc to work, but I can't remember now which function. I have tried to look at the comments to figure out which function, but still can't find it.

Comment: Its the fluidanimate benchmark from PARSEC.

Comment: Is your program multithreaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments in the source code of the allocator:

> Tread-safety: NOT thread-safe unless USE_LOCKS defined non-zero
>
> When USE_LOCKS is defined, each public call to malloc, free, etc is surrounded with a lock. By default, this uses a plain pthread mutex, win32 critical section, or a spin-lock if if available for the platform and not disabled by setting USE_SPIN_LOCKS=0.

You need to compile the library with `USE_LOCKS`, otherwise you may see crashes.

Another possibility is that your program exhibits undefined behavior that does not lead to consequences with the regular `malloc`. For example, it might write one byte past the allocated area somewhere, but that byte could be part of a memory chunk that is a few bytes larger than what you have requested. Use valgrind to check your program for memory errors with "regular" malloc before linking it with the custom allocator.